# C++ Builder - Piece.cpp(20): E2316 'Button1Click' is not a member of 'TForm'

Tags: c++, c++builder, chess

I have to make a chess program in C-builder for my OOP course. (object oriented programming)

I made a class Piece and created, inside this class, a TImage imPiece. Now I want to assign this image an Event OnClick using a function from the main class.

Piece.cpp

```
Piece::Piece(unsigned int, unsigned int, TForm* fJoc)
{
        imPiece = new TImage(fJoc);
        imPiece -> Parent = fJoc;
        imPiece -> Stretch = true;
        imPiece -> Transparent = true;
        imPiece -> Visible = true;
        imPiece -> Width = 36;
        imPiece -> Height = 36;
        imPiece -> OnClick = fJoc -> Move;
}

Piece::~Piece(){}
```

formaJoc.cpp

```
void __fastcall TfJoc::Move(TObject *Sender)
{
        exit(0);
}
```

formaJoc.h

```
class TfJoc : public TForm
{
    /* ... not quoted parts of class declaration */
    void __fastcall Move(TObject *Sender);
    /* ... not quoted parts of class declaration */
};
```

Error:

> [C++ Error] Piece.cpp(20): E2316 'Move' is not a member of 'TForm'

Comment: Don't post images or links to images. Post actual code and actual error messages. What is unclear about the error message? Tform has no such member.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments.  **Edit** your post with code.

Comment: @user1320881 I want to create an event to a TImage from a class created by me and use a function from c-builder class.

Comment: I'd like to help you, but firewalls are blocking your link.  Please **copy the code** into your question (not a screen snapshot).  I believe C++ Builder allows you to select lines of text, then copy to the clipboard.  Next, edit your question and paste the code.  Finally, select all the code in your post and click on {} or press Ctrl-K to format.

Comment: What is your *event*?  How is the event processing a `TImage` instance?  What function from C-Builder (or is that C++ builder) are you accessing?  Edit your question with the code that answers these questions.

Comment: Please edit your post with the declaration of class `Piece`.

Comment: Also, look at the `TForm` class to see if it has a `Move` method.  Look at its super classes to see if they have any `Move` class.

Comment: I recommend you change your design strategy.  A chess piece is not an image, but a chess piece *contains* an image (the image should be member not inherited).  A piece may also contain a position and color as well.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The function Move is in class TfJoc. But my compilator takes it from class TForm.

Comment: Your title mentions `Button1Click`.  Where is this function?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have class for each piece. I use imPiese in each class to take the coordinates and the image for each piece.

Comment: Button1Click is in class TfJoc : public TForm

Comment: The `fJoc` parameter is of type pointer to `TForm` as stated in the parameter list, not `TfJoc`.

Comment: I renamed the function from Button1Click to Move so that's why.

Comment: So how do I call TfJoc?

Answer (score 1):

Look very carefully at your `Piece()` code.  It has its own `fJoc` input parameter that is of type `TForm*`.  When it tries to access `fJoc->Move`, and compiler complains:

> 'Move' is not a member of 'TForm'

And that error is correct.  The `TForm` class does not have a member named `Move`.  `Move` is actually a member of your `TfJoc` class instead.

So, you need to either

1. change the input parameter to `TfJoc*` instead of `TForm*`
2. just get rid of the input parameter altogether and use the global `fJoc` pointer that is declared in `formaJoc.h` (assuming your `TfJoc` object is auto-created at program startup).

Comment: How to change input parameter? I only have TForm in class TfJoc: public TForm.

Comment: I renamed all TForm to TfJoc and, apparently its working now. Now I just need to figure out how to make pieces move randomly. I got each piece with each coordinate.

Comment: @Anton-CristianMocanu that is a separate question that [you already asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41411091/).